# how to publish a react js website on gitlab

Tags: reactjs, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner, website-deployment

i created a static react js project and i pushed it to git-lab excluding node modules. But now i am not able to publish my website it is showing deploy failed. but the build was successful. i know that i should make some changes to packagejson file but i dont know what all changes to be done. kindly please guide me in this issue

```
npm ERR!     npm bugs my-app
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls my-app
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /builds/Adithyets/react-website/npm-debug.log
Cleaning up file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: Try:

   rm -rf node_modules to remove  -  then  -  
    npm install to re-install

Comment: @JonahG thank you for responding. Could you please explain what was the error in this deployment and its background process that lead to this deployment error because i wish to know more about this error. And further It would be very helpful if you mention about the changes that take place while running the commands that you recommended.

Comment: if it worked ill make it a solution but it deletes the node_modules folder and then reinstalls them